# How to parse SerializeObject to Json array object jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some SerializeObject from HTML and i need to parse this object.

Array:

```
{"FormSheetTemplateId":55,"FormSheetTypeId":1,"StationTypeName":"CUTTING_MACHINE","StationTypeId":3,"Name":"1.7 TEST","TemplateColumns":["1","2","3"],"TemplateData":"["1","2","3"]","IsActive":true,"LanguageCode":"en","RenditionLanguagesDictionary":{"":"","uk":"UK","mk":"MK"},"FormSheetTemplateRenditions":[{"FormSheetTemplateRenditionId":13,"FormSheetTemplateId":55,"LanguageCode":"en","FormSheetTemplateRenditionColumns":["1","2","3"],"FormSheetTemplateData":"["1","2","3"]","DateCreated":"2020-10-30T13:50:13.6402756+02:00","UserCreated":"UserName","DateUpdated":null,"UserUpdated":null}],"DateCreated":"2020-10-30T13:50:12.7027324+02:00","UserCreated":"UserName","DateUpdated":null,"UserUpdated":null}
```

I try to use:

```
 $.each(array, function (index, template) {
});
```

But i have error, how i can parse this object?

Expected output:

```
"FormSheetTemplateId" : 55,
"FormSheetTypeId" : 1,
"StationTypeName" : "CUTTING_MACHINE",
...
```

Comment: Please add proper detail as what the expected output and your input

Comment: @BasheerKharoti i add expected output

Comment: @BestMoments use `JSON.parse` to parse your json

Comment: Your input and output seems the same...

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON file is faulty.

This code `"TemplateData": "["1 "," 2 "," 3 "]",`

Can you change it: `"TemplateData": "['1', '2', '3']",`

and

this code `"FormSheetTemplateData": "[" 1 "," 2 "," 3 "]",`

can you change it: `"FormSheetTemplateData": "['1', '2', '3']",`

Your file is object, not array.

You can use `Object.keys()`

You can debug the error for json file [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/qBaWKPx